# Displayed Activity Android

Tags: android

I want to create a app locker. it works well for android app lock lower than 4.03 and work on android 2.0 to 4.03 , but not working for 4.04. Here is my problem :

In android 4.04 , I got this message for running on each app :

```
08-16 15:43:00.291: I/ActivityManager(533): Displayed shortComponentName: +329ms
```

but in lower versions , I got app package name :

```
08-16 15:43:00.291: I/ActivityManager(533): Displayed com.test.app/com.test.app.Lock +329ms
```

how can I get package name on android 4.04

I have testet with Galaxy S3

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Despite your problem, you will no longer be able to read logs of **other applications** (unless you run on rooted device).

Answer (score 1):

If you are parsing logs in order to achieve this, I would recommend you stop doing this as soon as possible. Android 4.1 Jelly Bean no longer allows third party apps to look at the logs of other third party apps, so any solution that depends on logs will inevitably break.

Other than that, you'll have to be more specific about what you are doing... I can't really tell what you are trying to do from the logs you have posted.